# How to get previous volume from Binance Websocket NPM Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, binance

I actually like this [Binance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binance) NPM package as it has all I needed with the exception of the previous volume. When I called the Websocket it generates this result

This is the code

```
const api = require('binance');
const binanceWS = new api.BinanceWS(true);
const streams = binanceWS.streams;
 var a1, a2;
binanceWS.onCombinedStream(
    [
     streams.ticker('BNBUSDT')
    ],
    streamEvent => {
        switch (streamEvent.stream) {
            case streams.ticker('BNBUSDT'):
             
             console.log(streamEvent.data);
        }
    }
);
```

This is the result output

```
{
  eventType: '24hrTicker',
  eventTime: 1619449920389,
  symbol: 'BNBUSDT',
  priceChange: '16.76000000',
  priceChangePercent: '3.251',
  weightedAveragePrice: '519.27886943',
  previousClose: '515.46000000',
  currentClose: '532.33000000',
  closeQuantity: '0.45580000',
  bestBid: '532.32000000',
  bestBidQuantity: '2.19100000',
  bestAskPrice: '532.33000000',
  bestAskQuantity: '1.04910000',
  open: '515.57000000',
  high: '550.00000000',
  low: '478.01000000',
  baseAssetVolume: '3522095.68610000',
  quoteAssetVolume: '1828949865.91213540',
  openTime: 1619363520328,
  closeTime: 1619449920328,
  firstTradeId: 245583877,
  lastTradeId: 247300470,
  trades: 1716594
}
```

I can see the previous and current close prices, is there any way I can get the same for the volume of both quoted and base assets? So that it'll be `previousBaseAssetVolume` and `previousQuoteAssetVolume`.